# Numeric test in bash: integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell, test

I created a simple script in bash language to do cleaning of the recycle bin in Ubuntu.

here is the script "recycle.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
PUBLIC_PATH="/home/fileserv/.recycle/Public"
##### Clean public recycle folder
if [ !$(ls $PUBLIC_PATH | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
     /bin/rm -R $PUBLIC_PATH/*
fi
```

But when I run `# ./recycle.sh`
I encounter thise error:

```
./recycle.sh: line 4: [: !1: integer expression expected
```

Can somebody explain why? Any solutions to make it work?

Comment: `!1` is not an integer, put a space in there, or better yet just use `-ne` for not equal to.

Comment: The whole test condition is unnecessary here. Just remove all files - if there are no files in the directory nothing will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
#!/bin/bash
PUBLIC_PATH="/home/fileserv/.recycle/Public"
##### Clean public recycle folder
if [[ !$(ls $PUBLIC_PATH | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]; then
    /bin/rm -R $PUBLIC_PATH/*
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, it works !  (idk, why adding a symbol '[ ]' make it works)

Comment: There are some special primitives that `[[`  is defined to have, but `[` may be lacking(depending on the implementation), includes negation `!` or checking a file is older or newer than the other file `-ot or -nt` etc etc.. Again, it's a big topic. This should be a different question.